# I want my program to accept file paths via command line

Tags: c#, .net

To put it quite simply, I've been working on a text encryptor that deals with opening and saving encrypted files. However, when I click the encrypted file outside of the program, it of course opens my program and passes a path to Main(string[] args). However, I have no clue how to get the path name from the array(So I can't auto open the file when my program starts). Currently my program is called, opened, and displays an empty text box, just like when its opened under regular circumstances.

Edit: This has been resolved using

> string path = args[0];

Comment: Modify your program as follows: In the beginning of `Main`, add `foreach(var s in args) Console.WriteLine(s); Console.ReadLine();` (assuming a console app). Open the file. What does it print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args` parameter is just a string array, as indicated.

The first parameter passed will be `args[0]`, the second will be `args[1]`, and so on.

In this case, assuming the path is the only parameter passed you would use

```
string path = args[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correct, you want to get the values from the args array?

You could loop through each string to inspect the values:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     foreach (string arg in args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
     }
}
```

And you pass arguments like so:
>>> MyProgram.exe "argument1" "argument2"

Output, (from my example):
>>> argument1
>>> argument2